# Nested Collection View Data Binding Scope issues, using SQLite as Source. Xamarin Forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

Good Day Everyone. I hope I can explain my problem precisely.
I am working on making a Restaurant App and my SQLite DataBase has two tables, each from one class. There is also a One-To-Many Cascade option set from the User class, to the Pick class.

User Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RestaurantApp.ViewModel
{
    public class User : IUserPrimaryKey
    {
        

        [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public bool HasPaid { get; set; }
        public bool IsBoy { get; set; }

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
        public List<Pick> UsersOrder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Pick Class

```
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
namespace RestaurantApp.ViewModel
{

    public class Pick : IPrimaryKeyPresent
    {
        [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
       
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }

            
        [ForeignKey(typeof(User))]
        public int UID { get; set; }
    }

}
```

All is well and good so far. Now for the problem. I am attempting to Show in a Collection View, a list of all Users vertically. As you can see from the User class, it contains a property called UsersOrder, which is a List of Picks. This UsersOrder, I would also like to show this in another collection view, nested into the first one.
So each User in the first List, will contain a visual list of their orders, making up the second list.

For my ViewModel, I create the two tables needed, populate them with fake data, and create an ObservableCollection property of type User, which I will then Bind to my Xaml File to Show the list of users

UserVierModel Class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using RestaurantApp.DataBaseHelper;
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions;

namespace RestaurantApp.ViewModel
{
    public class UserViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        SQLiteConnection connection = Constants.connection;
        public UserViewModel()
        {
            

            connection.CreateTable<User>();
            connection.CreateTable<Pick>();

            for (int i = 0; i < Users.Count; i++)
            {

                User person = Users[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < menu.Count; j++)
                {
                    Pick pick = menu[i];
                    connection.Insert(pick);
                    
                }
                connection.Insert(person);
                person.UsersOrder = menu;
                connection.UpdateWithChildren(person);
                
            }
        }
        

        public User RetrieveUser(User u)
        {
            User user = connection.GetWithChildren<User>(u.UserID);
            return user;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<User> RetrieveAllUsers()
        {
            List<User> users = new List<User>();   
            users = connection.GetAllWithChildren<User>();
            
            ObservableCollection<User> temp = new ObservableCollection<User>(users);
            return temp;
            
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Pick> RetrieveUsersOrder(User user)
        {
            List<Pick> users = user.UsersOrder;
            ObservableCollection<Pick> temp = new ObservableCollection<Pick>(users);
            return temp;

        }

        

        private ObservableCollection<User> _UsersFromDataBase;
        public ObservableCollection<User> UsersFromDataBase
        {
            get
            {
                _UsersFromDataBase = RetrieveAllUsers();
                return _UsersFromDataBase;
            }

            set
            {
                _UsersFromDataBase = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        public ObservableCollection<User> Users
        {
            get => _Users;
            set
            {
                _Users = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        List<Pick> menu = new List<Pick>()
        {
            
                new Pick { Title = "The Ultimate Pack", Image = "IMG05.png", Description = "Prime beef burger topped with pepper jack cheese and crispy bacon.", Price = "$23.99" },
                new Pick { Title = "Lamb Bundle", Image = "IMG04.png", Description = "Lamb leg cooked in a Thai style yellow curry, with baby corn, string beans and chilies.", Price = "$19.99" },
                new Pick { Title = "Juicy Mushroom", Image = "IMG01.png", Description = "Wild mushroom and pea in a parmesan risotto served with crispy fried chicken.", Price = "$25.25" }
            
        };

        private List<Pick> GetMenu()
        {
            return new List<Pick>
            {
                new Pick { Title = "The Ultimate Pack", Image = "IMG05.png", Description = "Prime beef burger topped with pepper jack cheese and crispy bacon.", Price = "$23.99" },
                new Pick { Title = "Lamb Bundle", Image = "IMG04.png", Description = "Lamb leg cooked in a Thai style yellow curry, with baby corn, string beans and chilies.", Price = "$19.99" },
                new Pick { Title = "Juicy Mushroom", Image = "IMG01.png", Description = "Wild mushroom and pea in a parmesan risotto served with crispy fried chicken.", Price = "$25.25" }
            };
        }

        private ObservableCollection<User> _Users = new ObservableCollection<User>()
        {
            new User{ HasPaid = false, IsBoy = false, Name = "David Orakpo", Price = 20 },
            new User{ HasPaid = false, IsBoy = false, Name = "John Daniels", Price = 20 },
            new User{ HasPaid = false, IsBoy = false, Name = "Jones Madrid", Price = 20 },
            

        };
        
    }
}
```

So far so Good as well. Now to the Xaml.
I set the Binding Context to the UserViewModel

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:UserViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

I create my Nested Collection View (CV), assign the Top Level CV to "UsersFromDataBase", then assign the inner collection view, to the User Property, "UsersOrder"

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gold" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="40,0,40,0" Spacing="30">
            <Frame>
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding UsersFromDataBase}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*" ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UserID}"/>
                                <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsLayout="VerticalList" ItemsSource="{Binding UsersOrder}">
                                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto" ColumnSpacing="15">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="#A5A5A5" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="87" HeightRequest="40"/>
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="75" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                <StackLayout x:Name="stack" Grid.Column="1" Spacing="5" WidthRequest="115">
                                                    <Label  Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="White" FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="White" FontSize="10"/>
                                                 </StackLayout>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                </CollectionView>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
```

On my simulator, the first list of Users Loads fine, But the inner list remains blank. I don't know how else to expose it. Is this a Binding Context Issue? This is what I'm thinking. Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: nesting Collection/List views is generally not a good idea

Comment: @Jason How would you recommend I go about it

Comment: @SentryCOD Hi, do you mean want to one item of first `CollectionView` will contain second `CollectionView`?